# Change download folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, path

I am working on asp.net (mvc) project
I have to use method which provides possibility to download files by its url and download it into project map `~/App_Data/uploads/Docs` to this path, and I cant find method to specify where the file will be saved.

The method which I found to download by URL:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string pathAndName = Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads/Docs"), "stack.png");
    client.DownloadFile("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/51d065150eba7bfe5b6379e4caaaae88?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG", pathAndName);
}
```

How could I fix that issue?

Comment: See also [Writing data to App_Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574587/writing-data-to-app-data).

Comment: dang! I was just writing an answer to this

Comment: the end of your line of code `"stack.png");` is where the problem is occurring as you need to give it a path. 

for instance is `"stack.png");` was changed to "c:\\temp\\stack.png" that would then download your file to c:\temp. 

this is just psudo code, but should give you an indication of where you want to save it if you want to use special folders 

`Path.Combine(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments.ToString(), "downloadFolder", "stack.png");`

which will return as 

> MyDocuments\downloadFolder\stack.png

Comment: @Simon well, I can advise you to first search for a duplicate before starting to write an answer, as a _lot_ of questions that get asked per day have in fact been asked and answered before. As for your comment: you don't want a web server to download to My Documents, and the OP mentioned the AppData folder.

Comment: I have tried this as second parametr of  DownloadFile function `"C:\\Users\\DmitrijsS\\Desktop"+newDoc.docFileName` but the file was not saved

Comment: @Geeky yes it was, but not on the desktop, as you're missing a backslash. It will be saved to `"C:\\Users\\DmitrijsS\\DesktopSomeFilename"`. Again, see duplicate and the question from my first comment to get your answer. Also, use `Path.Combine()` to form paths, not string concatenation.

Comment: @CodeCaster that folder was just an example

Comment: heres the edited path ` Path.Combine(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData.ToString(), "downloadFolder", "stack.png");`

Comment: I edited, this is the way it should work? I am sorry for being so slow today... but I really cant get it. in this case Server keyword `does not exist`

Comment: Search before asking (or editing a new question into your question). See [Using Server.MapPath in MVC3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600118/using-server-mappath-in-mvc3).

Comment: Sorry, just have 20 minutes to deadline.. and hate to create report as well, so I wanted to get an answer while I am writing report, without searching on my own, I admit that it is bad thing to do...